# Coney and rabbit: what’s the difference?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Are the words *coney* and *rabbit* full synonyms in English? Are there any slight differences in usage or meaning? Are there any cases when one word is more appropriate in the modern writing or speech than another one?

Merriam-Webster and Wiktionary reference *coney* as a rabbit (especially, the European rabbit) without additional remarks. The OED does the same, but with a note *British & Heraldry*.

Comment: Hello Denis! Questions that can simply be answered by quoting or linking to a dictionary definition are off topic on EL&U! However, this question can be improved by reporting  what you are searchig for and what confuses you! -1 for vagueness!

Comment: Can we have some context, please? *Conies* in Psalm 104:18, for example, does not mean *rabbits*.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coney) for some more instances of what it could refer to.

Comment: When I hear _coney_, I think [hot dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coney#Food), not rabbit.

Comment: @J.R. And whence the same *Coney Island*?  It was the Isle of Cunny Bunnies, just as the Canary Islands were the Isles of the Dog.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, that was just a word for a foreign animal, in this case, the hyrax.

Comment: I was curious; being a resident of S.E. US, when I happened to look in the label of a fur coat belonging to my 45yr old daughter, given to her when she was less than two yrs old. It was a gift from her godmother from Peru, S.A. The label read: Coney fur made in Spain. L.P.Ulloa. Atlanta, Ga. 5-30-13 I am caucasian, married name given to me by my late husband, a native and physician from Peru, S.A. who became a citizen of U.S.

Comment: Summary: unless you are a chef or Tolkien fanatic, 'coney' is an unrecognizable word to the great majority of English speakers. If a rabbit runs in front of you and you say 'Look at that coney!', everyone else will say 'What's a coney? Is it behind that rabbit?'

Comment: "Coney" is essentially unused in the US today, except as the first name of "Coney Island".  It's doubtful that most would know what you meant if you used the term.  "Bunny", "hare", and "cottontail" would be far more familiar.

Comment: I read somewhere that rabbit was the unborn young of a coney I am 70 years old & was french in its origin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Of Leporids and Country Matters

***Rabbit*** or ***hare***, and familiarly ***bunny***, are now the common words for the critters once commonly called ***coney***.  The OED reports that *coney* is now in “more or less familiar use with game-keepers, poachers, game-dealers and cooks”.  J.R.R. Tolkien alluded to this in *The Hobbit*, for 
as all readers of  Tolkien know, a *coney* is just an older name for a rabbit, as Bilbo observes when interrogating Gandalf about Beorn the skin-changer, and which Sam later cooks up in a stew:

- ‘What! a furrier, a man that calls rabbits conies, when he doesn’t turn their skins into squirrels?’ asked Bilbo.
- Our bread chokes you, and raw coney chokes me.
- If you give me a coney, the coney’s mine, see, to cook, if I have a mind.
- Sam busied himself with his pans. ‘What a hobbit needs with coney,’ he said to himself, ‘is some herbs and roots, especially taters – not to mention bread.
  There’s some left, if you want to try stewed coney.’
- We shall have it like a coney in a trap.
- But now he has done worse trespass than only to go coney-snaring in the uplands: he has dared to come to Henneth Annyn, and his life is forfeit.

Rabbits are something of an anachronism in Tolkien’s legendarium, not being native to the historical region he was depicting, so he usually chose an older word to describe them.  Our word *rabbit* originally meant only the young, not the full-grown version, for which *coney* was reserved. The OED tells an interesting tale for the word *coney*:

> 1. - **a.** A rabbit: formerly the proper and ordinary name, but now superseded in general use by rabbit, which was originally a name for the young only.
>    - **b.** Still retained in the Statutes, and in more or less familiar use with game-keepers, poachers, game-dealers and cooks: in market reports, now usually meaning a wild rabbit.
>    - **c.** It is also the name in Heraldry.
>    - **d.** *dial.* In some districts applied to a young rabbit, but elsewhere more properly to an old one.
>    - **e.** (without *pl.*). The flesh of the rabbit.
> 2. - **a.** The skin or fur of the rabbit. (The earliest recorded use in Eng.) *Obs*. or *dial*.
>    - **b.** A hat made of rabbit-fur (in place of beaver). *U.S.*
> 3. In O.T. used to translate Hebrew *shāphān*, a small pachyderm (*Hyrax Syriacus*), living in caves and clefts of the rocks in Palestine.
> 4. Applied also locally to the Cape Hyrax or Das (*Hyrax Capensis*), and to the Pika or Calling Hare (*Lagomys princeps*) of the Rocky Mountains; also with qualifications to other small quadrupeds.
> 5. - **† a.** A term of endearment for a woman. *Obs.*
>    - **b.** Also indecently.
> 6. † A dupe, a gull; the victim of the ‘cony-catcher’. *Obs.*
> 7. - **a.** Some kind of shell-fish; ? a cone.
>    - **b.** A name for the Nigger-fish (*Epinephelus punctatus*) of the West Indies.

As you see by sense 5b, it turns out that *coney* used to rhyme with *honey* and *money*, but this was just too punny for its own good.  One of the citations for sense 5b:

> - 1622 Massinger *Virg. Mart.* ɪɪ. i ―A pox on your Christian cockatrices! They cry, like poulterers’ wives, ‘No money, no coney’.

So why do we today rhyme *coney* with *bony* instead of with *bunny* as we once did?  Too many uncunning punsters, basically, giving it a vulgar sense. Shakespeare himself did this, as shown later in this posting.

Here the OED’s etymology for *coney*:

> The current form represents OFr. *conil, connil,* cogn. w. Pr. conil, Sp. *conejo*, Pg. *coelho*, Ital. *coneglio*:-L. *cunīcul-us* rabbit (also burrow, underground passage, military mine), according to ancient authors a word of Spanish origin. The OFr. pl. (with l suppressed) *coniz*, later *conis*, gave an Eng. pl. *conys*, *conies*, and this a singular *cony, conie*. The ME. *cunin, konyne, conyng* was a. OFr. *conin, connin*, Anglo-Fr. *coning*, a parallel form to *conil*, which gave also MDutch *conijn*, Dutch *konijn*, and, with *a* for *o*, LG. *kanîn*, whence mod.G. dim. *kaninchen*. In Eng. the form *cunyng, cunning* came down to the 16th c.; but from the 12th c. onward it varied also with *cunig, conig, connyg*.
>
> The historical pronunciation is with /ʌ/; common spellings from 16th to 18th c. were *cunnie, cunney, cunny,* and the word regularly rimed with *honey, money,* as indicated also by the spelling *coney*; but during the 19th c. the pronunciation with long *ō* has gradually crept in. This pronunciation is largely due to the obsolescence of the word in general use, while it occurred in the Bible, and esp. in the Psalms, as the name of a foreign animal (sense 3); the oral tradition being broken, readers guessed at the word from the spelling. It is possible, however, that the desire to avoid certain vulgar associations with the word in the *cunny* form, may have contributed to the preference for a different pronunciation in reading the Scriptures. Walker knew only the *cunny* pronunciation; Smart (1836) says ‘it is familiarly pronounced *cunny*’, but *cōny* is ‘proper for solemn reading’. The obsolescence of the word is also a cause of the unfixed spelling; the Bible of 1611 has *conie, cony, conies,* modern editions *coney, conies* (cf. *money, monies*), an irregularity retained in the Revision of 1885.
>
> The rabbit is evidently of late introduction into Britain and Northern Europe: it has no native name in Celtic or Teutonic, and there is no mention of it in England before the Norman period; in the quotations the fur, perhaps imported, appears before the animal. The Welsh *cwning, cwningen,* is from ME.; the Irish *coinnín*, and Gaelic *coinean, coinein* from ME. or AFr.

About the time that *coney* was getting bad press for its punny association with *cunny*, the word *bunny* appeared as a more clean-minded but still rhyming synonyn for the rabbit version, making it something of a minced oath.  But the pun was already there in the original Latin *cuniculus*, so it’s been with us for a long time.

In *As You Like It*, Shakespeare has Rosalind liken herself to a coney when she’s speaking to Orlando “like a saucy lackey, and under that habit play the knave with him”:

> **Orlando**. Where dwell you, pretty youth?
>
> **Rosalind**. With this shepherdess, my sister; here in the skirts of 
>   the forest, like fringe upon a petticoat.
>
> **Orlando**. Are you native of this place?
>
> **Rosalind**. ***As the coney that you see dwell where she is kindled.***
>
> **Orlando**. Your accent is something finer than you could purchase in
>   so removed a dwelling.

Notice it’s a decidedly female coney that Rosalind mentions. Shakespeare is being naughty there — or saucy, as he himself put it.  Under the historical pronunciation /ʌ/ used in Shakespeare’s thyme, the actor speaking that like would have rhymed *coney* with *honey*, and audiences of that age all would have got the joke, just as they did when Shakespeare elsewhere wrote of “country matters”.  Without the necessary rhyme, the intended sauciness may well be lost on latterday audiences.

Rabbits and hares are in the [Leporid family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leporidae), which along with ***rock coneys***, make up the [Lagomorph order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagomorpha).  Rock coneys are a local name for the pika, as OED sense 4 explains.  However, it now goes by a different genus: it’s actually  [*Ochotona princeps*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pika).  But it’s still a coney, even though it isn’t a rabbit or a hare.  Sometimes people even call it a whistling hare — not that it is a hare, mind you.  Regular folks are very particular about common names for things, you see.

So *coney* is a sort of older, local, or rustic name for any leporid or even lagomorph, one perhaps still favored by Bilbo’s furriers.

Another place you might come across *coney* is in the dialect word ***to coney-fogle***, also spelled ***connyfogle***. It means to ingratiate oneself, to cheat by bewildering.  [Sources: the *English Dialect Dictionary*, and also *Provincial Words and Expressions Current in Lincolnshire* (1866).] This is probably related to the OED’s sense 6 of being a dupe, not to its leporid sense 1, although *coney-fogle* does sound rather vulgar if you’re a punny-bunny about both halves of the compound.

*Coney-fogle* may have given rise to the later U.S. colloquialism ***to honey-fuggle***, again meaning to dupe, deceive, or swindle, but not quite so vulgarly.  Still seems a bit naughty, though, especially if you haven’t heard it before.

Comment: This is right on. I believe that "coney" is more common in certain demographics and quite rare in others, leading the other answerers to declare that they've never or rarely heard it in use. In my own rural midwestern American demographic, though, it's uncommon but no more uncommon than eating rabbit.

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive answer.  I'm from North Yorkshire and my granddad was a gamekeeper.  For years as a kid, I never quite equated rabbits (white fluffy things the neighbours had as pets) with coneys (grey/brown pests that got shot and eaten)

Comment: Interesting - if 'rabbit' used to be the name given to the young, any idea why rabbit young are now called kits/kittens?

Comment: "... and which Sam later cooks up in a stew" - here I had to re-read it as I didn't recall Sam cooking Beorn.

Answer (score 7):

I've only heard the word *coney* in one context:

> I've treacle and toffee, I've tea and I've coffee,
>   Soft tommy and succulent chops;
>   I've chickens and conies, and pretty polonies,
>   And excellent peppermint drops.
>
> (from Little Buttercup's Song, HMS Pinafore, [Gilbert and Sullivan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_and_Sullivan))

In that usage, it's a full synonym. From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=coney):

> *Rabbit* arose 14c. to mean the young of the species, but gradually pushed out the older  word 19c., after British slang picked up *coney* as a punning synonym for *cunny* "cunt". The word was in the King James Bible, however, so it couldn't be entirely dropped, and the solution was to change the pronunciation of the original short vowel (rhyming with *honey, money*) to rhyme with *boney*.

So, yes, it's a full synonym, but out of use these days, unless you're into musicals.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for the spelling correction. Good grief, I must have been tired.

Answer (score 6):

I've never heard the word *coney* before.

The OED has five sub-definitions for *coney* meaning *rabbit*. The first four the most recent citations in the late 19th century, and the fifth in the 16th century:

> **a.** A rabbit: formerly the proper and ordinary name, but now superseded in general use by *rabbit*, which was originally a name for the young only.
>
> **b.** Still retained in the Statutes, and in more or less familiar use with game-keepers, poachers, game-dealers and cooks: in market reports, now usually meaning a wild rabbit.
>
> **c.** It is also the name in *Heraldry*.
>
> **d.** dial. In some districts applied to a young rabbit, but elsewhere more properly to an old one.
>
> **e.** (without *pl.*). The flesh of the rabbit.

Other definitions of *coney* or *cony* are for rabbit fur, a number of other small animals, a term of endearment, and a kind of shell-fish.

Therefore, unless you're going to use *coney* in a very specific context where it has a special meaning for your audience, you're better off using the much more well-known *rabbit*.

Comment: Goof answer, but bear in mind there are situations where an unfamiliar word for *rabbit* is positively desirable; at the butcher's, for example, or when discussing your new fur coat.

Comment: I suspect that you've never heard it quite possibly because rabbit's not a regular part of your diet. As eating rabbit became more rare, a specialized term for rabbits-as-food became more rare.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, its been a long time since I last read Enid Blyton; but I recall coming across 'coney' in some Famous Five books.

IIRC it wasn't used as an exact synonym for rabbit; the impression I got was a local smaller variety of rabbit (something like a country mouse instead of a city mouse e.g.)

Answer (score 3):

In most (if not all) of the USA, *coney* is a word for a [smallish hotdog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coney_Island_hot_dog).

[image]

The first time I heard it used in a context that clearly called for a game animal, you can imagine how confused I was.

The animal here is referred to only as a Rabbit or a Bunny (sometimes Bunny-Rabbit). I almost never hear "hare" used, unless somebody is trying to make a pun of some kind. I have *never* heard "coney" used to refer to the animal in conversation. Only in literature.

Comment: [A *hare* is not the same animal as a *rabbit*](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Hare_vs_Rabbit)!

Comment: @tchrist - Scientifically, yes. However, the words are typically used interchangeably. Trying to figure out which is which (in North America at least) is a real challenge. Here's Wikipedia on the confusion: "Four species with "hare" in their common names are not considered true hares: the hispid hare (Caprolagus hispidus), and three species known as red rock hares (Pronolagus spp.). Meanwhile, jackrabbits are hares rather than rabbits."

Answer (score 3):

The 'Journal of Thomas Dineley' on his tour of Co. Clare, Ireland in 1681 — "Cony Island took its name from the great number of Rabbits and Coneys there..."— seems to suggest, at that time, coneys were distinct from rabbits. Maybe hares?

Comment: I don’t know of any hares native to that area.

Comment: @tchrist - Clearly the author thought there was *some* difference in nuance between the two words. Perhaps he was using "rabbit" in the old sense the OED references as "a young coney" ("coney" being roughly what we call "rabbit" today)